# Convergence in distribution and find limit

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

For $n \geqslant 1$ , let [Fn:R ->[0,1]] ,be 
    $Fn(x) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0{\text{                 for x < 0}}  \\
  1 - {(1 - x)^n}{\text{    for 0}} \leqslant {\text{x}} \leqslant {\text{1}} \\
  1{\text{                  for x > 1}}  \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

(1) find the $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } Fn(x)$

Solution    $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } Fn(x) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0{\text{   for x < 0}}  \\
  1{\text{    for }}x \geqslant 0{\text{                  }} \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

```
It True or false  ?  If true how we show
```

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } [1 - {(1 - x)^n}] = 1$
    Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is correct; If $0<x<1\implies0<1-x<1$, then 
$$y=(1-x)^n\implies \ln{y}=n\ln{(1-x)}\implies\ln{(\lim_{n\to \infty}y)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\ln{(1-x)}\to-\infty\implies\lim_{n\to \infty}y\to 0$$